# Как присвоить значения указателю на статическую переменную типа структуры находящейся в класса в c++?)

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, sfml, struct

```
#ifndef PALETTE_HPP
#define PALETTE_HPP

#include "coreMinimal.hpp"

namespace kp
{
    using stateColor_t = kp::Palette::StateColor;

    class Palette
    {
    public:
        struct StateColor
        {
            sf::Color shape;
            sf::Color outline;
            sf::Color text;
            sf::Color marker;
        };

        static const kp::stateColor_t* m_active;
        static const kp::stateColor_t* m_inactive;
    };
}

#endif // !PALETTE_HPP
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение.

Palette.hpp:

```
#ifndef PALETTE_HPP
#define PALETTE_HPP

#include "coreMinimal.hpp"

namespace kp
{
    struct StateColor
    {
        sf::Color shape;
        sf::Color outline;
        sf::Color superimposed;
        sf::Color text;
        sf::Color marker;
    };

    class Palette
    {
    public:
        static const kp::StateColor* m_active;
        static const kp::StateColor* m_inactive;
    };
}

#endif // !PALETTE_HPP
```

Palette.cpp:

```
#include "Palette.hpp"

const kp::StateColor* kp::Palette::m_active = new kp::StateColor
{
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255)
};

const kp::StateColor* kp::Palette::m_inactive = new kp::StateColor
{
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
    sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255)
};
```